# Check if exists in perl returning always true

Tags: perl

I have a  subroutine in perl to check if array contains particular element if it contains return TRUE else false..The below code should retun false since the searched element http_TestABC is not in array but still it returning TRUE.Not able to figure why this happens.Any pointers appreciated
Thanks

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;


my @result_listosp;     # defines an empty array

$result_listosp[0] = "origin-server-pool-1"; # array has one element
$result_listosp[1] = "http-pool-OSP2"; # array has 10 elements now
my $osp="http_TestABC";
my $status_osp_check= check_if_entity_exists(@result_listosp,$osp);
print $status_osp_check;

sub check_if_entity_exists()
{
    my @entityarray = @_;
    my $entity = $_[1];

    my $status="FALSE";

    if ( grep( /^$entity$/, @entityarray ) ) {
      $status="TRUE";
      return $status;
    }
    else {
      return $status;
    }
}
```

Comment: `$entity` contains the second element of your `@result_listosp` array. Assigning something to `@_` does not modify `@_`.

Comment: Do not do this `grep( /^$entity$/, @entityarray )` since `$entity` can contain regexps, also its slow. More clear way: `grep { $_ eq $entity}  @entityarray`

Comment: As well as the other great advice that you have received, I'd also strongly recommend *not* using the strings 'TRUE' and 'FALSE' as your Boolean values. You'll find things get far easier of you use values that Perl actually treats as true or false (for example 1 and 0).

Comment: @DaveCross So much good advice its hard to fit into one answer. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It always returns true because you have misunderstood how to pass arguments to a subroutine. When you do this:

```
my @entityarray = @_;
my $entity = $_[1];
```

You assign all of the arguments to `@entityarray` and the second argument to `$entity`. So of course if you check all elements of one against `$entity` it will be one of them.

You also should not use prototypes, the parentheses that follow the sub name. Unless you know what they do, they are best ignored, as they have a very special functionality.

The solution, reverse the arguments:

```
check_if_entity_exists($foo, @bar);
...
sub check_if_entity_exists {
    my $entity = shift;     # the first arg
    my @entityarray = @_;   # the rest
```

This happens because perl flattens the array when it is passed as an argument, so it becomes just elements in the argument list, not a single variable. Perl has no way of knowing whether you passed an array or not. *Unless* you play around with prototypes. Which I **do not recommend** other than as an exercise. If you do something like:

```
sub foo (\@$) {
```

Then you can actually pass an array as an argument, much like `push` and `shift`.

You can also pass the array as a reference, in which case you do something like so:

```
foo(\@array, $var);

sub foo {
    my $aref = shift;    # @$aref is now @array
    my $var  = shift;
```

In this case, you need to beware that you are using the *same* array that you passed to the subroutine, not a copy. So if you change it, changes are permanent.

Note: As [PSIAlt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1671032/psialt) points out, you should not use an arbitrary string directly in a regex, if your intent is to match literally. There may be meta characters in it that cause side effects. Do either:

```
grep /^\Q$entity/, ..       # quote meta characters
grep { $_ eq $entity } ...  # check string equality
```

as PSIAlt suggests, `eq` is the most straightforward solution, and unless you need regex power, should probably be the one you use.

Comment: and also, `prototypes`, ah

Comment: Thanks you gave amazing explanation I am new to perl hence this mistake

Comment: @loldop Yes, prototypes are the thing people love to hate, though, and not without reason. :P

Comment: I would probably do `my($entity,@entityarray)=@_;` or just use `@_` after shifting off `$entity`.

Comment: @BradGilbert I kind of like the latter one because it looks sleek, but in reality it doesn't much matter. I would say go for the most readable one, but that's rather subjective too.